# Возможно ли с помощью модуля multiprocessing запускать методы класса в процессах?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли запускать методы класса в процессах? Есть код:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
...
extractor = VKExtractor(args.login, args.password)
...
extract_processes = []
if args.day:
    extract_processes.append(Process(target=extractor.extract_day, args=(profile_id, display_name)))
for extract_process in extract_processes:
    extract_process.start()
for extract_process in extract_processes:
    extract_process.join()
```

Вывоит ошибку `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. Метод класса не статический.